# Unity struct is serialized, but not editable from component menu

Tags: c#, struct, unity-game-engine, serializable

I have a struct in Unity which is declared like this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public struct IntVector2 {
    public int x, z;

    public IntVector2 (int x, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.z = z;
    }
    public static IntVector2 operator + (IntVector2 a, IntVector2 b) {
        a.x += b.x;
        a.z += b.z;
        return a;
    }
}
```

Then, I added an `IntVector2` as a field on a script. When I looked at the script component on the sidebar, the struct and its variables were nowhere to be found. What am I doing wrong?
EDIT: Here is the code of my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Maze : MonoBehaviour {
public IntVector2 size;

public MazeCell cellPrefab;

private MazeCell[,] cells;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
public MazeCell GetCell (IntVector2 coordinates) {
    return cells[coordinates.x, coordinates.z];
}
public float generationStepDelay;
public IEnumerator Generate () {
    WaitForSeconds delay = new WaitForSeconds(generationStepDelay);
    cells = new MazeCell[size.x, size.z];
    IntVector2 coordinates = RandomCoordinates;
    while (ContainsCoordinates(coordinates) && GetCell(coordinates) = null) {
        yield return delay;
        CreateCell(coordinates);
        coordinates += MazeDirections.RandomValue.ToIntVector2();
    }
}

private void CreateCell (IntVector2 coordinates) {
    MazeCell newCell = Instantiate(cellPrefab) as MazeCell;
    cells[coordinates.x, coordinates.z] = newCell;
    newCell.name = "Maze Cell " + coordinates.x + ", " + coordinates.z;
    newCell.coordinates = coordinates;
    newCell.transform.parent = transform;
    newCell.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(coordinates.x - size.x * 0.5f + 0.5f, 0f, coordinates.z - size.z * 0.5f + 0.5f);
}

public IntVector2 RandomCoordinates {
    get {
        return new IntVector2(Random.Range(0, size.x), Random.Range(0,       size.z));
    }
}

public bool ContainsCoordinates (IntVector2 coordinate) {
    return coordinate.x >= 0 && coordinate.x < size.x && coordinate.z  >= 0 && coordinate.z < size.z;
}
}
```

The one that is not shown is `size`

Comment: and the code of your script...?

Comment: Sorry about that! Edited!

Comment: it works on mine, do you have the struct in its own cs file or is it inside a class, when i made the struct its own cs file it worked for me

Comment: Works here as well. You must be doing something else you're not showing us... Or it's just a typo or something like that, but this code is ok.

Comment: It's in its own cs file, and this is the copy-pasted code.